# making document viewer start from the last page

Tags: 16.04, pdf

The document viewer is I think the best for reading pdf files, but after I formatted my PC, it doesn't remember the last page I was on, how can I configure the default ubuntu document viewer to remember the last page I was on before I closed the pdf the last time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`evince` stores the last page and per-document viewing options *by default*, in typical GNOME fashion, cannot even deactivate it.

The information is stored in two files in `$HOME/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/`, `root-<4bytes>.log` and `home-<4bytes>.log`. If you delete them, `evince` should generate new ones after the next start of the program and work as expected.

Comment: but my evince somehow doesn't do this. Why could this be?

Comment: Look if the folder mentioned above exists and is writable. Delete the `root-*.log` and `home-*.log`, if they are already there. `evince` should now work for future files you open with it. Check if new files are generated when you open `evince`.

Comment: the latter folder is not available

Comment: And I deleted the folder as you said, but evince didn't create it again, when I restarted it

Comment: however, I restored the items from the recycle bin and changed the permissions of the files that existed in the folder, and it worked!! Thanks

Comment: doesn't work for me in 20.04. I think it is a necessary feature for a document viewer. Would really like to make it work.